# Installing PyCrypto on Ubuntu - fatal error on build

Tags: python, pycrypto

Having looked at other similar threads, I still can't get pycrypto running.

I'm trying to get it working on my Ubuntu laptop - but I couldn't manage it on my Windows PC either.

I downloaded pycrypto-2.6, extracted it, and ran

```
    python setup.py build
```

but then this happened

```
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 - fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-?2.7/src/MD2.o
src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You have no developing header for python. However, if you just need the module why don' you install by easy_install or pip ?

Comment: Same error using easy_install (without the python-dev package).

Comment: Same error using pip (without the python-dev package).

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You need to install the Python development files.  I believe this will do it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: 'sudo zypper in python-devel' for OpenSuse

Comment: For Python3: `apt-get install python3.2-dev` or `apt-get install python3.3-dev`, depending on distro

Comment: `sudo dnf install python-devel` if you are in Fedora.

Comment: @NirvanaTikku had the answer that saved my life for python3.X .

Comment: for python 3.6: `apt-get install python3.6-dev`

Comment: for python 3.5: `apt-get install python3.5-dev`

Comment: for any python 3 version: `apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: Just for those who arrives here with centos... ``yum install python-devel`` or ``yum install python36-devel``

Answer (score 22):

On Ubuntu, I needed some other packages for it to succeed:

```
apt-get install autoconf g++ python2.7-dev
pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: It also works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I wonder why the wheel is missing from pypi for this package?

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu and if you use Python 3.x you will need:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc python3-dev
```

you probably already have gcc but just in case if you are trying this command from Dockerfile with base image python:3.6.4-slim-jessie then you will also need gcc.

Comment: i actually needed to run `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev` after running/installing `sudo apt-get install python3.7` not sure why `python3-dev` doesn't cover this via apt-get dependencies, but it works.

Comment: @Edward your comment just saved me in AWS CodeBuild in July 2021.. possibly post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**August 2021**

For python 3.8 users run

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

and try to install pycrypto again

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: It's better to use "python3-dev", which is a meta package that will automatically choose the correct package based on the installed python version.